# The option “Allow this application to be used to Sign in with Twitter?” in my Twitter app setting is not editable. How to enable?

Tags: twitter

The documentation of Twitter API says (https://dev.twitter.com/web/sign-in/implementing):

> To use the “Sign in with Twitter” flow, please go to your application
>   settings and ensure that the “Allow this application to be used to
>   Sign in with Twitter?” option is enabled.

But this option in the setting of my freshly created app is not editable. Please see the picture. Why is it not editable? How to enable?

UPD: It is impossible to set "twitter-api" tag! It just disappears when I click "Save Edits".

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to go back to "Settings" in your Twitter app. In the Application Details section, "Sign In with Twitter" permission is a small checkbox under the Callback URL box.